# Catch thrown exception in Junit without Throwable block swallowing it

Tags: java, junit4

I have a class that divides two numbers. When a number is divided by 0, it throws ArithmeticException. But when I unit test this, on console it is showing that ArithmeticException is thrown, but my test is failing with an AssertionError. I want to know if there is a way to prove that it is throwing ArithmeticException in Junit?
Example.java

```
public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Example ex = new Example();
    ex.divide(10, 0);
}

public String divide(int a, int b){
    int x = 0;
    try{
        x = a/b;
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Caught Arithmetic Exception!");
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        System.out.println("Caught a Different Exception!");
    }
    return "Result: "+x;
}
}
```

ExampleTest.java

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @Test(expected=ArithmeticException.class)
    public void divideTest()
    {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.divide(10, 0);
    }
}
```

My actual code is different, since that has lot of dependencies, I simpflied my requirement to this example test. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`divide` isn't throwing this exception.

Your options are

- extract the inner portion of the try/catch as a method you can call from the unit tests.
- capture the System.err in the unit test and check it tries to prints the error you expect.

You can extract the method using your IDE like this

```
public static String divide(int a, int b){
    int x = 0;
    try{
        x = divide0(a, b);
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("Caught Arithmetic Exception!");
    }
    catch(Throwable t){
        System.out.println("Caught a Different Exception!");
    }
    return "Result: "+x;
}

static int divide0(int a, int b) {
    return a/b;
}

@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)
public void testDivideByZero() {
    divide0(1, 0);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you said. Can you please give me an example code.

Comment: @pavanbairu I have added an example for refactoring.

Comment: That helped. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `AssertionError` because the expected exception, `ArithmeticException`, didn't get thrown by the test method.  You need to let the `ArithmeticException` propagate out of the method to be tested, `divide`.  Don't catch it.  Don't catch anything in `divide`.

Comment: like I mentioned in my comments, this is just an example code I wrote to make you understand my requirement. But, in my actual code, I need to catch that exception in my class and unit test the same. Please suggest.

Comment: That was not clear from your question description.  Your `divide` method needs to return a `String`.  Have it return `e.getClass().getName()` in your `catch` block(s).  Then have your test method `assertEquals` that the returned string is `java.lang.ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit isn't catching the exception because you've already caught it in your method. If you remove the try catch block in "divide", JUnit will catch the arithmetic exception and your test will pass

Comment: like I mentioned in my comments, this is just an example code I wrote to make you understand my requirement. But, in my actual code, I need to catch that exception in my class and unit test the same. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your `divide()` method is catching the ArithmeticException but not doing anything with it (other than printing to console that it was caught). If the `divide()` method is supposed to throw the ArithmeticException, then you have two choices:

- Remove the try/catch within the `divide()` method. As soon as you attempt to divide by 0, it will automatically throw an ArithmeticException, and your test case will pass upon receiving the expected Exception class.
- Or, after printing to console that an ArithmeticException was caught, **throw** that exception back up to the calling method.

Comment: Second one is a good idea, but I need to return something even after catching the exception. Peter's example worked for my requirement. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question and update the test case to reflect that. Currently it is expecting the ArithmeticException to be thrown (@Test(expected=...)) and it's failing because the divide() method is swallowing it instead of throwing it.